# Removing a taxonomy term

Tags: tags, array, terms

There is a Wordpress function called wp_remove_object_terms that unfortunatly doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to achieve the same ends using the following

```
    $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );



                if( $post_terms ){
                    if(($key = array_search($term_id, $post_terms)) !== false) {
                        unset($post_terms[$key]);
                    }
                    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $post_terms, $taxonomy, true );
                }
```

This doesn't work, not sure where I am going wrong. Here is the code in the context of the function it sits in

```
add_action('admin_init', 'update_custom_tour_groups');

    function update_custom_tour_groups(){

        $taxonomy = 'custom';

        $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( "hide_empty" => 0 ) );

        foreach( $terms as $term ):

            //Get the term id of the current term
            $term_id = $term->term_id;
            //Create the acf string to get the acf field on the current term page eg custom_awesome-tours
            $acf_value = $taxonomy.'_'.$term_id;

            //wp_set_post_terms, used later, needs to term id as a number (int)
            $term_id_int = (int)$term_id;

            //Loop through all tours in the custom taxonomy and remove the term we are currently looping through
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'tours',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
            );

            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);       
            if( $the_query->have_posts() ): 

                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ): 

                    $the_query->the_post();

                    $post_id = $post->ID;

                    //$post_id_int = (int)$post_id;

                    //Remove the current term from this post. Basically this remove all posts from the current term
                    //wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id_int, $term_id, $taxonomy );
                    //wp_delete_object_term_relationships( $post_id, $taxonomy );
                    $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );

                    /*
                    echo 
                    '
                    <script>
                    alert("'.$post_terms.'");
                    </script>
                    ';
                    */

                    if( $post_terms ){
                        if(($key = array_search($term_id, $post_terms)) !== false) {
                            unset($post_terms[$key]);
                        }
                        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $post_terms, $taxonomy, true );
                    }

                endwhile; 
            endif;

            //Loop through each tour that has been selected on this term page
            $post_objects = get_field('tours_in_group',$acf_value);


                if( $post_objects ): 

                    foreach( $post_objects as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT)

                        $post_id = $post->ID;

                        $term_id_array = array( $term_id_int ); //Specially formatted to work with wp_set_post_terms

                        //Add the current term to the selected post
                        wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $term_id_array, $taxonomy, true );

                    endforeach; 

                endif;

        endforeach; 
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is last argument in [`wp_set_object_terms()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_set_object_terms/) call. You are setting `$append` to `true`, so it essentially checks if input is already present and does nothing else.

You want it set to `false` (which is also default) so that terms are *forced* to be same as input and difference (what you removed) is deleted from post.

Comment: Thanks Rarst. Unfortunately making the above change doesn't fix the issue. I expect you are correct and there is also a second issue which I can't put my finger on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to the party but the error is that you are searching a multidimensional array. You have to specify for the key you are searching for

`$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
if( $post_terms ){
    if(($key = array_search($term_id, array_column($post_terms, 'term_id'))) !== false) {
        unset($post_terms[$key]);
    }
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $post_terms, $taxonomy, false );
}`